# Power of a second-order tensor

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products, tensors

I have the following equation:

$$
\dfrac{\mathbf{V}^T \cdot \mathbf{V}}{\mathbf{V}^T : \mathbf{V}} + \dfrac{\mathbf{V} \cdot \mathbf{V}^T}{\mathbf{V} : \mathbf{V}^T} = \dfrac{\mathbf{D}^2}{\left \| \mathbf{D}^2 \right \| }
$$

With:
$$
\mathbf{D} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \mathbf{V}^T + \mathbf{V}\right)
$$

$$
\left \| \mathbf{D}^2 \right \| = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \mathbf{D}^2 : \mathbf{D}^2\right)}
$$

Now, what is the square of a tensor? The same as matrix power?
$$
\mathbf{D}^2 = \mathbf{D} \cdot \mathbf{D}
$$

Comment: What is the source of this.

Comment: That URL doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{V}^\intercal\mathbf{V}^\intercal$ is the same as $(\mathbf{VV})^\intercal$ since
$$(V^\intercal V^\intercal)^i_j=(V^\intercal)^i_k(V^\intercal)^k_j=V^k_iV^j_k=(VV)^j_i=((VV)^\intercal)^i_j$$
Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier in the paper they write
$$\mathbf{L}=\nabla\boldsymbol{v}=\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{D}$$
Where $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a velocity vector. This is a $(1,0)$ tensor. Correspondingly, its covariant derivative $\nabla\boldsymbol{v}$ should be a $(1,1)$ tensor, or matrix. To make the equation consistent, this means that both $\mathbf{W},\mathbf{D}$ are matrices as well. So $\mathbf{D}^2$ just means $\mathbf{DD}$. To further confirm that this is the case, they have defined $\mathbf{W},\mathbf{D}$ as the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of $\mathbf{L}$,
$$\mathbf{W}=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{L}-\mathbf{L}^\intercal) \\ \mathbf{D}=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{L}+\mathbf{L}^\intercal)$$
Clearly the expression $\mathbf{L}+\mathbf{L}^\intercal$ is nonsense if $\mathbf{L}$ is not a tensor of type $(p,p)$.

---

**Rant:**

This is why I abhor any mathematics written by engineers. For instance they have written in the paper
$$L_{ij}=\nabla_jv_i$$
Which makes it look as though $\mathbf{L}$ is a $(0,2)$ tensor. But what they should have written is
$$L^i{}_j=\nabla_jv^i:=(\nabla v)^{i}{}_j$$
$\boldsymbol v$ is a *vector*, and so it should have up, not down, indices.

Comment: @Trailer No. $\mathbf{D}^2=\mathbf{DD}$. It is quite literally just matrix multiplication.

Comment: Ok, but it should really be written as $D^i{}_kD^k{}_j$. This is exactly matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{D} \cdot \mathbf{D}$ is not matrix multiplication. It is True that a dot product of two second order tensors can always be carried out by the multiplication of two matrices, but those matrices are not necessarily the components of the two tensors. Let me show an example:

$\mathbf{A} = a_{km}\mathbf{e}^{k}\mathbf{e}^{m}$ and $\mathbf{B} = b_{km}\mathbf{e}^{k}\mathbf{e}^{m}$ In this case $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} = a_{km}g^{mj}b_{jn}\mathbf{e}^{k}\mathbf{e}^{n}$ where the metric tensor appears as $g^{mj}$. If the frame is a Cartesian one, the metric tensor is the identity tensor, and indeed, the operation simplifies to a matrix multiplication, but this is only for a special case.